# How to pass parameters into a os.system() syntax in python?

Tags: python

```
os.system('python manage.py ogrinspect  data/Parking.shp Parking --srid=4326 --mapping --multi > output.txt')
```

Variable A = "Parking" .

How can I substitute A everywhere os.system() has Parking ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?  Are you asking how to substitute a python variable into a call to os.system?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Yeah . I want to put A.shp where A = "Parking" , that is A is a string variable containing Parking

Comment: As I remember, you can NOT use PIPE operation in os.system. You may also need to notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call os.system with a string you're invoking a shell and get shell expansion regardless of whether you want it or not. It can lead to unexpected security issues when you start inserting variables (particularly user-supplied variables).

Instead of using os.system, checkout subprocess.call() or subprocess.check_call() and pass it a tuple or list of arguments. When you pass it a list or tuple it doesn't need to start a shell to process the arguments.

By using a list or a tuple you can easily have your variables in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make substitutions in the string you pass to `os.system` (or any other function), you can use string interpolation:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> "abc %s def" % a
'abc foo def'
>>> b = "apples"
>>> "hello %s %s" % (a, b)
'hello foo apples'
>>> "hello %(c)s %(d)s %(c)s" % {'c': a, 'd': b}
'hello foo apples foo'
>>>
```

You can't (as in some other languages, like PHP, Ruby or TCL), name arbitrary variables in the current scope using string interpolation; variables must be enumerated, and passed in as a tuple or dict.

Answer (score 0):

Or in Python3

```
new_text = ''
url = 'www.google.com'
if new_window:
    new_text = '--new-window'
os.system(f'google-chrome-stable {new_text} {url}')
```